# What is a REST response, what does it do?

Tags: rest, jersey, response

I had made a REST webservice using redirecting to various paths like if i need to delete some user then i will redirect the user to this address in the `@Path` annotation  :

```
user/delete
```

and therefore there is no thing like RESPONSE i have used.
While going through a code given to me by my senior i came accross these lines :

```
java.net.URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(id).build();
Response.created(uri).build();
```

What are these lines doing, i have no idea.
Can someone explain me this w/o wiki links or any other 'Basic Rest Service' links.

Answer (score 0):

Without any explicit details about the uriInfo object I can only speculate its type is the JAX-RS UriInfo class.

The first line can be broken down as below:

> java.net.URI uri = uriInfo.**getAbsolutePathBuilder**().path(id).build();

The getAbsolutePathBuilder is documented http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePathBuilder%28%29

> java.net.URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().**path(id)**.build();

The method returns a UriBuilder object. On which the 'path(...)' method is called passing the id so if the absolute path returned http://www.host.com (this may or may not have a port number) adding the id in this method will then result in the effectively Builder holding the two parts. The base URI and the path. The two values have not yet been put together

The build method then concatenates the two values resulting a full URI. For example http://www.google.com/id (Where http://www.google.com is the absolute path)

The second line

> Response.created(uri).build();

Is basically saying 'Respond with a created (201) response code, and set a Location header containing the build uri value'